Gradle Android build failed when using NFS PVC as cache on k8s
Gradle Android build failed when using NFS PVC as cache on k8s。
The reason for the failure is 'Duplicate class', and I suspect it may be due to some class path issues.
But it only reproduces on NFS PVC, and it won't fail when I use OpenEBS PVC or Host PVC.
I created multiple PVCs for testing, but NFS PVC always leads to build failures
PS. I also tested different types of read-write modes, and the results showed that no matter which read-write mode was used, nfs PVC always failed.
gradle build output:
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$1 found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$AccessibilityDelegate found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$ChildAccessibilityDelegate found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$SavedState found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$SavedState$1 found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$SimpleDrawerListener found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     Duplicate class androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout$ViewDragCallback$1 found in the following modules: drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (android-gif-drawable-release@1.2.23.aar), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.media:media:1.0.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:memory-type-java:2.5.0), drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:nativeimagetranscoder:2.5.0) and drawerlayout-1.0.0-runtime (com.facebook.fresco:soloader:2.5.0)
     
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


Could some one explain why NFS PVC cause the 'Duplicate class'?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
